# page template with custom post type loop case page duplication

Tags: custom-post-types

Custom post type created with this arg

```
'labels' => $labels,
'hierarchical' => false,
'description' => 'Custom post type for question and answer',
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail' ),
'public' => false,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => false,
'menu_position' => 24,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-editor-help',
'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
'publicly_queryable' => false,
'exclude_from_search' => true,
'has_archive' => false,
'query_var' => false,
'can_export' => true,
'rewrite' => false,
'capability_type' => 'post'
```

The loop inside the page template to show this custom post type contant 
PS/1: in the wordpress reading setting POSTS to show 100 in page 
PS/2: this permalink been used archive page for this custom post type

```
'post_type' => 'question', 'posts_per_page' => -1
```

I have 24 posts.

The problem is when visiting `%link/thispage/page/2/`, 
`%link/thispage/page/3/`, 
`%link/thispage/page/4/`, 
`%link/thispage/page/5/`, 
`%link/thispage/page/6/`, 
`%link/thispage/page/7/`, 
`%link/thispage/page/8/` even `%link/thispage/page/100/`

How i can avoid subpages for custom post type if there is no more posts to show and also how to avoid subpages for pages that include loop for custom post type that show all -1 posts

Comment: will as i had answerd dipen under here this a wordpress Super mega SEO bug ... try any page created in wordpress and add link /page/3/ to /page/100000000/ it will have the same content which my own Competitors sent to index and really harm my serp resluts. 

Thanks for Jeff Starr - https://perishablepress.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will as i had answerd dipen under here this a wordpress Super mega SEO bug ... try any page created in wordpress and add link /page/3/ to /page/100000000/ it will have the same content which my own Competitors sent to index and really harm my serp resluts.

[Wordpress Infinity loop](https://perishablepress.com/wordpress-infinite-duplicate-content/)
Thanks for Jeff Starr - https://perishablepress.com

```
global $posts, $numpages;

$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$result = preg_match('%\/(\d)+(\/)?$%', $request_uri, $matches);

$ordinal = $result ? intval($matches[1]) : FALSE;

if(is_numeric($ordinal)) {

    // a numbered page was requested: validate it
    // look-ahead: initialises the global $numpages

    setup_postdata($posts[0]); // yes, hack

    $redirect_to = ($ordinal < 2) ? '/': (($ordinal > $numpages) ? "/$numpages/" : FALSE);

    if(is_string($redirect_to)) {

        // we got us a phantom
        $redirect_url = get_option('home') . preg_replace('%'.$matches[0].'%', $redirect_to, $request_uri);

        // if page = 0 or 1, redirect permanently
        if($ordinal < 2) {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
        } else {
            header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 302 Found');
        }

        header("Location: $redirect_url");
        exit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is connected to has_archive set to false in your code. So you need to set ‘has_archive’ to true in register_post_type()
'has_archive' => true,
And then Please flush permalinks after you update that property.
I believe it should help.
Also, you might need to create a custom template for archive of this CPT, check this section of the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates).

Comment: dipen, thank you for ur answer, but i wont this custom post type to be publish at all or indexed by SE just i wanna use it in some secations in the pages, but seems this a wordpress big bug for SEO, Why try to add /page/2/ to /page/10000000/ and the page will be there this means content duplicate. i had found small snap code which really helped me to avoid any content duplication issuse will update it in my mean post